# Logitech K120 Spanish keyboard composite key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, composite

I'm using MX Linux 23.2, my keyboard is Logitech K120 Spanish, during installation, I chose 104key-pc keyboard, but when trying to configure composite key to create accent char (such as á, à, ã, ç, etc.), it does not work, either the accent does not show up or only showed up after several tries, which keyboard should I choose with my keyboard to enable composite key?

Comment: You need to choose the layout that matches your keyboard. In your case, assuming it's European Spanish (Latin American variants ARE different), you'd select Spanish (with dead keys). Also check this tool https://mxlinux.org/wiki/help-files/help-mx-system-keyboard/

Comment: @ChanganAuto, sorry for the late reply, did not get the notification, thanks for this tip, I'll give it a try.